# busybox initramfs loop mount

Tags: kernel, mount, busybox, initramfs, loop-device

I'm trying to loop mount my root filesystem (a loop file) within a busybox initramfs.

I try to run the command:

mount /rootfs.raw /root

... which works on my Ubuntu laptop, however, I simply get

`mount: mounting /dev/loop0 on /root failed: Invalid argument`

No matter what combination of options I use, (including loading to /loop0 manually and trying to mount it), the system will not mount the loop device.

Why can't I mount it?

Comment: Have you tried `-o loop`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to solve this problem, I had to be more verbose about my mounting command. I ended up using:

```
modprobe loop
mount -t iso9660 -o loop /bootpart/rootfs.raw /root
```

This worked properly.

Answer (score 1):

According to [mount(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mount):

> **EINVAL** source had an invalid superblock.  Or, a remount was  attempted,
>                 but  source  was  not  already  mounted  on  target.  Or, a move was
>                 attempted, but source was not a mount point, or was '/'.

Of which the first failure seems the most likely and is easy enough to check with

```
fsck /rootfs.raw
```

Does the machine you are trying to mount upon have the loop driver built in or loaded? Try

```
grep loop /proc/devices
```

If not, is loop a loadable module? Try

```
# modload loop
```

Are there loop-device block i-nodes in place? What does

```
ls -l /dev/loop*
```

show? Does the major number correspond to the driver number in `/proc/devices`?